# getopt 3 different arg handle in program

Tags: python, getopt

my project is handle three arguments how to handle this my code like this

```
def main(argv):
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"d:f:w:",['--i','--u','--v'])
    print opts
    print args

except getopt.GetoptError:
    print 'Option Error'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main(sys.argv[1:])
    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
```

i will run this code i will get this ouptut ./code.py -d --i -f --u package1 package2
output is

```
[('-d', '--i'), ('-f', '--u')]
['package1', 'package2']
```

but i will expect output like this format how to modify,
**./code.py -d --i package1 -f --u package2 ...**

```
[('-d', '--i',), ('-f', '--u')]
['package1', 'package2']
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood how the getopt works.
The parameters are of getopt are `getopt.getopt(args, options[, long_options])`.
That means in your case

```
-d equals --i
-f equals --u
-w equals --v
```

For the long options, a good practice is to give them long names. E.g.:
    -d should equal --destination.

For further reference see http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html#getopt.getopt.

So the correct CLI command in your case should be either

```
./code.py -d package1 -f package2
```

OR

```
./code.py -d package1 -f package2
```

OR even mixed

```
./code.py --i package1 -f package2
```

Where *opt* for first parameter will be 'd' and *arg* for the first parameter will be 'package1'.